# C++ Using a for loop to count cumulative sum of user-entered integers

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am new to learning code, and am currently taking a class with the C++ language. For this assignment, we are supposed to design a "vending machine kiosk", and are told to use while loops, if-else statements, and a for loop to calculate the total at the end. I feel okay about the while loop and if-else statements, but I am still unclear on how to use a for loop for static user inputs, and I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
while (choice == 1 || 2 || 3) {
    cout << "Available sodas and prices:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Coke - $1" << endl;
    cout << "2. Pepsi - $0.50" << endl;
    cout << "3. Root Beer - $0.25" << endl;
    cout << "4. Finish and calculate total" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of the soda you would like to purchase: ";
    cin >> choice;
    // IF ELSE STATEMENTS TO DETERMINE SODA'S PRICE
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "How many Cokes would you like?: ";
        cin >> amount1;
        cout << "The total amount for " << amount1 << " Cokes is: $" << amount1 * 1 << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "How many Pepsi would you like?: ";
        cin >> amount2;
        cout << "The total amount for " << amount2 << " Pepsi is: $" << amount2 * 0.5 << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        cout << "How many Root Beers would you like?: ";
        cin >> amount3;
        cout << "The total amount for " << amount3 << " Root Beers is: $" << amount3 * 0.25 << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    // FOR LOOP TO CALCULATE TOTAL PRICE
    {
    for (int i = amount1; i = true; i * 1)
    {
        for (int j = amount2; j = true; j = j * 0.5)
        {
            for (int k = amount3; k = true; k = k * 0.25)
            {
                float total = i + j + k;
                cout << "Your total cost today is: $" << total << ". Thank you for shopping at the Soda Shop!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    else cout << "Invalid option. Please select a valid soda choice or choose 4 to finish." << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    continue;
    }
```

I apologize if my code is really ugly or unreadable, as I am still very new to the process. Attempts to google information on for loops have only brought up the same things my teacher taught in lecture, which is things like printing numbers in sequence or multiplication tables.

Thank you to anyone that provides any illuminating information. This is very confusing to me.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. We do not need to see all the code, only what is relevant for your specific question. Though, you should not strip away the `main`, includes and all the rest that is needed to compile this. Also clearly state what is your next step, what exactly is missing? What do you mean with "use a for loop for static user inputs" ?

Comment: Ehr??? `for (int i = amount1; i = true; i * 1)`... what do you want to do here? And have you heared about functions? Don't put all your code in one big blob

Comment: for example declaration of variables is missing here. Already the first line `while (choice == 1 || 2 || 3) {` to know if this is just slightly wrong or totally wrong we need to see code you do not show (correct it is not, thats not how you compare to several values)

Comment: "X is either A or B" in logic is "X is A or X is B" - `X == A || X == B`. `X == A || B` means "either X is A, or B is truth-y".

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to use a *loop* for calculating the total. You either misunderstood something, or your teacher has no idea what they're doing. (And your loops make no sense at all.)